# Make a lookup column in one list to show me the item that are on hand in another list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, lookup-column, administration

I have two list, the first one (tracker list) is a tracker or inventory of all the phones that I have on hands. Second list (request list) is for user request a phone by serial number.

I want to create a column on the request list that show the user only the phone serial number that I have on hand.

Example:

I will request a phone but I don't know the serial number of the phone that I want. Having a lookup column that show me all the serial numbers available depending on the tracker list that reflect that serial number is available.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using SharePoint list lookup columns. Follow below steps:

1. Go to your "tracker list" in SharePoint site.
2. Create a single line of text or number column for storing serial numbers in "tracker list" (as per your requirements). Follow: [Create a column in a list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/office/create-a-column-in-a-list-or-library-2b0361ae-1bd3-41a3-8329-269e5f81cfa2?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).
3. Now, go to your "request list" in SharePoint site.
4. Create a lookup column based on "tracker list" and select appropriate columns like serial number in lookup column settings.

**Microsoft documentation**: [Create list relationships by using lookup columns in SharePoint lists](https://support.microsoft.com/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).